# Solving a system of equations coming from Lagrange multiplier method

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to use Lagrange multipliers to find the points on a surface given by $g(x,y) = x^4+y^4-4xy = 6$ in $R^2$ which have the smallest and largest distance to the origin $(0,0)$. So $g(x,y)=6$ is my constraint, and the function I am minimizing is the distance $d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ which is equivalent to minimizing $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. So by the Lagrange multiplier method the system I have to solve is
$$ 2x = \lambda(4x^3-4y) $$
$$ 2y = \lambda(4y^3-4x) $$
$$ x^4+y^4-4xy = 6 .$$
The problem I'm having is solving this system for $\lambda$. I have tried to use the suggestion in this question ([Solve system of linear equations within a Lagrange multiplier problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010182/solve-system-of-linear-equations-within-a-lagrange-multiplier-problem)) and setting $y=xt$ (I'm not sure why we're even allowed to do this in the first place?). Plugging this into the first two equations and then dividing one by the other leads me to the quadratic $(x^2+1)t^2-x^2t-1 = 0$ in the variable $t$, which has solutions
$$ t = \frac{x^2 \pm \sqrt{x^4+4(x^2+1)}}{2(x^2+1)} $$
but this looks extremely messy and I'm not sure if it helps me to solve the original system? Am I on the right track, or is there any easier way?

Comment: Note that it is sometimes much less work to just ignore $\lambda$ and solve only for $x$ and $y$. We don't really care what $\lambda$ is--it is a helpful construct to set up the problem only. I have not verified if that is specifically useful in this case. You could start by taking the ratio of equations 1 and 2 which together with equation 3 give a system for just $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Right, thanks. I did what you suggested and got $(x,y)=(0,0),(\pm \sqrt{3}, \pm \sqrt{3}), (\pm 1, \mp 1)$ as solutions. The $(0,0)$ contradicts the original setup, so I'm left with the other four solutions. Is this an exhaustive list of the maxima and minima? Do I know they're maxima or minima just by plugging them back into $f$ and seeing which ones are largest/smallest? Also, if you have time please could you explain the reason why we're allowed to ignore $\lambda$? In other words, in which cases do we *really* care about $\lambda$? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is a correct alternative approach.

Comment: @GreenCoffee248 I cannot think of a case where we would care about $\lambda$. It's just that we know the gradient of the constraint function and target function are parallel, so we just add a proportionality constant to complete the picture. In fact since the constraint has the form $g(x,y) =c$, it seems we can scale it so $\lambda$ is anything we want.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-You have $\dfrac{x}{2x^3-2y}=\dfrac{y}{2y^3-2x}\Rightarrow (x^2-y^2)(1-xy)=0$. You can take now $x=y$ which gives $x^4-2x^2-3=0$ so $x=\sqrt3$ and
$$\lambda=\dfrac{x}{2x^3-2y}=\frac{\sqrt3}{18\sqrt3-2\sqrt3}=\frac{1}{16}$$
Complete the analysis with the other possible values.

Comment: I think we get two solutions from the quadratic in $x^2$, they are $x = \pm \sqrt{3}$, right? Also, as mentioned in the comments, once we get these solutions do we really need the Lagrange multipliers $\lambda$ anymore?

Comment: @GreenCoffee248: Yes because you want to have extremunm points and the solutions you find come from the use of such multipliers.